# How to set top and bottom drawablePadding in textView

Tags: android, android-layout, padding

The android:drawablePadding attribute exists in the TextView class. Helps to fill space between text and drawing in TextView. But is there a way to create upper and lower padding without custom views?

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            andtoid:drawableEnd="@drawable/arrow"
            tools:text="Text" />
```

Comment: show xml or viwe code in your question

Comment: Post a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: set drawable padding it will cover all the areas.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for answers. I achieved the result with TextView + ImageView, because there is no ways to create upper and lower padding of endDrawable in TextView.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only set padding on all sides for drawable in TextView.

Answer (score 0):

The android:drawablePadding attribute will give you the padding between your drawable and your text, if your drawable is on top or bottom, then you can change the upper or lower padding respectively, otherwise it is not possible to set it because there is no method or attribute related, as you can see in the [TextView's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablePadding(int)).

If you want a workaround you can change your drawable setting blank spaces or changing it's size, but the best solution would be making a custom view or using a third party library.

Depending on the case, you can also archive the padding you want setting the padding of the TextView itself and working with the size of the text and the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

Add this attribute in TextView `android:drawablePadding="10dp"` to set all direction equal padding. drawablePadding The padding between the drawables and the text.